# Add range and ><= operators to django form

Tags: django, django-forms, relational-database

I am building enterprise software which someone can use to input order data from a customer. Sometimes customers order something with length 1000+ or will order something within a range of 400-600 for example.

How can I display these options in a dynamic form which inputs an integer into a model? Will my model have to have max_length min_length, max_width, min_width etc or is there a better way?

I've considered creating non-required fields and dynamically displaying the form depending on a dropdown menu choice near every dimension with (greater than, equal to, less than). This will make me create around 6 new fields for a basic l/w/h input.

For example: If someone wants a range they can click on the side dropdown near the dimension and select range, which will then show a new input box which submits data to max_DIMENSION. Or when a user chooses > then the database saves that field as greater than.

I expect to be input a range with 2 values, or a >/=/< with a single value.

Comment: how are these options determined? are they pre-determined for each product? or can the customer just enter any value they want? It would help if you make this a little more concrete by giving concrete examples of products and values.

Comment: The static options for each dimension (length, width, thickness) are equals to, greater than, less than, and range. The thickness and width can be ex: equal to 38 but the length should be greater than 800. So the data reported would be width_condition = equals to, width_value = 38 and length_condition = greater than and length_value = 800. From this data i guess I’d be able to use the condition of each dimension for the logic flow. The hard part is the range where I’d have to display a second input box into the form called max_width, but maybe that’s bad practice im unsure.